# Why does shiny interprete functions as reactive?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I do not fully understand why this works:

```r
library(shiny)

ui = basicPage(
  sliderInput("x", label = "x value", min = 0, max = 100, value = 20),
  textOutput("out")
)
server = function(input, output, session) {
  val = function(pre = "") {
    paste0(pre, input$x)
  }
  output$out = renderText({
    paste(val("out: "))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Am I using some undocumented behavior?
Is there a cleaner approach to use functions that contain reactive objects?

Comment: which bit exactly is unclear - the fact you can use `input$x` inside a function?

Comment: Never noticed this behavior. Interesting! As for last part of your post, you can simply define your function outside `server()` or in `global.R` and pass reactive values to it inside `server.R`.

Comment: @SymbolixAU `input$x` is not in a reactive context.

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html - see the example just over half way down with `currentFib`

Comment: This type of behavior is described in the [Shiny Reactivity Overview](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html) in the last example of the "Reactive conductors" section. Basically the function call inherits the reactive environment of the `renderText()`. But you still can't successfully call the function outside a reactive environment.

Comment: ... and from a pedagogical perspective, having a function reference a variable that is neither defined internally nor passed to it renders the function frustratingly-resistant to reproducibility and confident troubleshooting. Perhaps it sounds judgmental (perhaps it is), but there are many times when problems stemming from this practice (due to a restarted R session and variables no-longer-found) are difficult to trace.

Comment: Good answers. @r2evans: Yes, but on the other hand you have reactive objects that "are functions without arguments" already.

Comment: In the cases of `reactive` and `observe`, then yes, I submit that they are an exception. However, a counter-argument is that unit-testing requires that each small function be testable, but by hard-coding `input$x` in your function, it cannot be tested; better to have some variable be passed as an argument (that may or may not be reactive in nature), so that the function can be validated outside of the shiny environment. (*Of course* you have 100% coverage on your shiny app functions, right? ;-)